# in clicking edittext box then don't open mobile keyboard this scenario how can implemented

Tags: android

I am implementing one application some fields are edittext in edittext clicking open mobile keyboard how can implemented this keyboard do not open

Comment: @satyamurthy, If an answer is working for you, please mark it as accepted. Not doing that will result in few answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) to show or hide the keyboard. In order to hide it, you should do something like:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```